# Cursor : div alignment

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my code I try to change the default slider to a customize version. When I hover on the first div, no worries it works fine
When I move my cursor over the video, the cursor changes but depending on the size of the screen I have the triangle and the rounded text that shift ... do you have a solution to fix this?
thanks

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".box");
var innerbox = document.querySelector(".innerbox");
var box2 = document.querySelector(".box2");
var cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
var cursorinner = document.querySelector(".cursor2");
var circle = document.querySelector("#circle");
var triangle = document.querySelector("#triangle");

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  cursor.style.transform = `translate3d(calc(${e.clientX}px - 50%), calc(${e.clientY}px - 50%), 0)`;
  cursorinner.style.left = x + "px";
  cursorinner.style.top = y + "px";
  circle.style.left = x + "px";
  circle.style.top = y + "px";
  triangle.style.left = x + "px";
  triangle.style.top = y + "px";
});
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
  cursorinner.classList.add("cursorinnerhover");
  circle.classList.add("click");
  triangle.classList.add("click");
});

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
  cursorinner.classList.remove("cursorinnerhover");
  circle.classList.remove("click");
  triangle.classList.remove("click");
});

box.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  cursor.classList.add("block");
  cursorinner.classList.add("block");
});
box.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  cursor.classList.remove("block");
  cursorinner.classList.remove("block");
});

innerbox.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  cursor.classList.add("hover");
});
innerbox.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  cursor.classList.remove("hover");
});

box2.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  circle.classList.add("opacity");
  triangle.classList.add("opacity");
});
box2.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  circle.classList.remove("opacity");
  triangle.classList.remove("opacity");
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap");
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background:red;
}

h1 {
  font-family: montserrat;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 1000px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.innerbox {
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.innerbox:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
.box {
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.box:hover, .box2:hover {
  cursor: none;
}
.box2 {
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.cursor {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(calc(-50% + 15px), -50%);
  display: none;
}
.cursor2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: fixed;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: width 0.3s, height 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  display: none;
}
.hover {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.cursorinnerhover {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.block {
  display: block !important;
}
.opacity {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
#circle {
  transform: translate(-49.9%, -4.5%);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
 #triangle {
  transform: translate(-1%, -0.7%);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  fill: white;
}
#circle text {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#circle circle {
  stroke: white;
  fill: none;
}
#circle svg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;

  -webkit-animation-name: rotate;
  -moz-animation-name: rotate;
  -ms-animation-name: rotate;
  -o-animation-name: rotate;
  animation-name: rotate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 5s;
  -o-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -o-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
} 

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    -o-transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
}
.click {
 fill: #E1E1E1!important;
 stroke: #E1E1E1!important;
 stroke-width:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Custom Cursor</h1>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="innerbox">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
     <video class="box2" controls loop id="video-background" muted>
  <source src="https://media-us-westslateappcom.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/madcowfilms/production/clips/514ebae1-ebbb-4477-addd-d52a30cd28c1-1280x720.2500.webm" type="video/webm">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="cursor"></div>
<div class="cursor2"></div>

<div id="circle">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
      <path id="circlePath" d=" M 150, 150 m -60, 0 a 60,60 0 0,1 120,0 a 60,60 0 0,1 -120,0 " />
    </defs>
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="50" fill="none" />
    <g>
      <use xlink:href="#circlePath" fill="none" />
      <text fill="#fff">
        <textPath xlink:href="#circlePath">Jouer la vidéo - Jouer la vidéo -
          <textPath>
      </text>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
<div id="triangle">
  <svg>
    <polygon points="45,22.5 22.5,0 22.5,45"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

or https://codepen.io/jipe974/pen/abjxoNy

Comment: hey- I would wrap triangle and circle in a container center the triangle in that container using flex and move that container using javascript

also you can use css for the spinning animation instead of javascript to simplify things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never work by mixing calculations of positioning in percentages with offsets. You must center your SVG elements by matching the viewBox values with their CSS sizing.
here is the code for the cursor you are having trouble with.

```js
const
  Surf    = document.querySelector('#surface') 
, cursorV = document.querySelector('#cursorVideo')
  ;
Surf.onmouseenter = e =>
  {
  cursorV.style.setProperty('--movXY', `${e.clientX}px, ${e.clientY}px`);
  cursorV.classList.toggle('noDisplay', false);
  }
Surf.onmousemove = e =>
  {
  cursorV.style.setProperty('--movXY', `${e.clientX}px, ${e.clientY}px`);
  }
Surf.onmouseout = e =>
  {
  cursorV.classList.toggle('noDisplay', true);
  }
```

```css
html {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  }
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(4, 32, 51);
  }
.noDisplay {
  display : none;
  }
#surface {
  margin : 100px;
  width  : 500px;
  height : 400px;
  background-color : black;
  cursor           : none;
  }
#cursorVideo {
  position : fixed;
  top      : -80px;  /* make center at 0 0 */
  left     : -80px;
  width    : 160px;
  height   : 160px;
  --movXY  : 0px,0px;                 /* variable CSS */
  transform: translate( var(--movXY));
  pointer-events : none;
  }  
#cursorVideo:not(.noDisplay) #circle {
  animation-name            : rotate;
  animation-duration        : 5s;
  animation-iteration-count : infinite;
  animation-timing-function : linear;
  }
@keyframes rotate {
  from { transform : rotate(360deg); }
  to   { transform : rotate(0);      }
  }
#circle {
  position : absolute;
  top      : 0;
  left     : 0;
  width    : 160px;
  height   : 160px;
  }
#circle circle {
  stroke       : #e1e1e1;
  stroke-width : 2;
  }
#circle text {
  font-family : "Helvetica Neue", Arial;
  font-size   : 24px;
  font-weight : bold;
}
#triangle {
  position : absolute;
  left     : 72px;   /* to center on cursorVideo element size */
  top      : 56px;  
  width    : 24px;
  height   : 48px;
  fill         : #e1e1e1;
  stroke       : #e1e1e1;
  stroke-width : 0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="surface"> test surface.. </div>


<div id="cursorVideo" class="noDisplay">

  <svg id="circle" viewBox="70 70 160 160"> <!--  correct viewBow -->
    <defs>
      <path id="circlePath" d=" M 150, 150 m -60, 0 a 60,60 0 0,1 120,0 a 60,60 0 0,1 -120,0 " />
    </defs>
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="50" fill="none" />
    <g>
      <use xlink:href="#circlePath" fill="none" />
      <text fill="#fff" id="circleTxt">
        <textPath xlink:href="#circlePath">
          Jouer la vidéo - Jouer la vidéo -
        </textPath>
      </text>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <svg id="triangle" viewBox="0 0 24 48"> <!-- correct viewBow values-->
    <polygon points="0,0 24,24 0,48" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little adjustment. I think you will get the point :)

```js
const _customCursor = document.getElementById("customCursor")
document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
 
  _customCursor.style.left = x + "px";
  _customCursor.style.top = y + "px";
  
});
```

```css
body{
  background:#0f0f0f;
  position: relative;
}

#customCursor{
  position: absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius:50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#triangle{
  transform-origin: -100% 50%;
  transform: translateX(35%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 50% 49%);
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="customCursor">
  <div id="triangle"></div>
</div>
```